# JavaFX Dialog getResult() method not returning the right generic type

Tags: java, generics, javafx, classcastexception

I'm facing a problem dealing with JavaFX `Dialog<R>` class. I created a dialog with a custom type parameter, say `String` for simplicity. Now whenever I try to acquire the result of the dialog I get a `ClassCastException`.

Take this simple JavaFX application:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Dialog<String> dialog = new Dialog<>();
    dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().setAll(ButtonType.OK);
    String result = dialog.showAndWait().orElse(null);
}
```

Once I hit the OK button, I have an error stack that leads to:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.control.ButtonType cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Needless to say, the code compiles perfectly. It seems that whenever the OK button is triggered, the value of the dialog box is forced to something of type `ButtonType`. Not the type you'd expecting knowing the method signature.

This is also true if I use the method `getResult()` after having shown the dialog.

I use Oracle's JVM 1.8.0_151.

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Dialog API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) requires you to set a result converter callback if the type is not `Void` or `ButtonType`. To get your example running:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Dialog<String> dialog = new Dialog<>();
    dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().setAll(ButtonType.OK);
    dialog.setResultConverter(ButtonType::getText);
    String result = dialog.showAndWait().orElse(null);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

In the snippet above, `result` holds the value `OK`. This is hardly more useful than having `ButtonType` as a type argument. If you want to obtain a domain object from the `Dialog`, a more idiomatic approach is to attach an event to the OK button, perform a validation on the input and calculate the result object in the event handler. The documentation lists three ways to achieve that.

Comment: Thank you Kiril. That indeed worked. I still find it weird though that a method doesn't really respect its signature.